# PyQGIS interpolation classes and triangulation file without interpolation raster

Tags: pyqgis, interpolation, tin

I am trying to interpolate lines using Interpolation plugin in QGIS. There is an option for exporting triangulation file. I don't want to create raster interpolation. In this case, I want only triangulation file. My code:

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsVectorLayer, edit, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsMapLayerRegistry
import qgis.analysis


resolution = 0.1
q5_edited = QgsVectorLayer("C:\\Users\\testuser\\Documents\\exp_q5_23.shp", "CONTOUR", "ogr")
q20_edited = QgsVectorLayer("C:\\Users\\testuser\\Documents\\exp_q20_23.shp", "CONTOUR", "ogr")

q5_index = q5_edited.fieldNameIndex('intpol')
q20_index = q20_edited.fieldNameIndex('intpol')

ld_q20 = qgis.analysis.QgsInterpolator.LayerData()
ld_q5 = qgis.analysis.QgsInterpolator.LayerData()

ld_q20.vectorLayer = q20_edited
ld_q20.zCoordInterpolation=False
ld_q20.InterpolationAttribute = q20_index
ld_q20.mInputType = 1 #1 = structureLines, 2 = breakLines

ld_q5.vectorLayer = q5_edited
ld_q5.zCoordInterpolation = False
ld_q5.interpolationAttribute = q5_index
ld_q5.mInputType = 1

itp = qgis.analysis.QgsTINInterpolator([ld_q20, ld_q5])
itp.setExportTriangulationToFile(True)
itp.setTriangulationFilePath('C:\\Users\\testuser\\Documents\\dualedge.shp')

rect = q20_edited.extent()
ncol = int((rect.xMaximum() - rect.xMinimum())/resolution)
nrow = int((rect.yMaximum() - rect.yMinimum())/resolution)

test = qgis.analysis.QgsGridFileWriter(itp,"C:\\Users\\testuser\\Documents\\dualedge_raster.tif",rect,ncol,nrow,resolution,resolution)
test.writeFile(True)
```

I set `setExportTriangulationToFile` to `True` and set the `setTriangulationFilePath` to path where I want to create triangulation file. But the triangulation file is created only when the last line is run `test.writeFile(True)`. This command creates triangulation file (.shp) and raster file (.tif). I checked the code of `writeFile` function (https://qgis.org/api/qgsgridfilewriter_8cpp_source.html) but I can't find the place where triangulation file is created I found only the writing to a raster file. I hoped there will be some function which creates triangulation file before creating the raster file.

**How the triangulation file is created and is it possible to create triangulation file without creating raster? I need it because we interpolate a very big vector data which makes raster really big and we don't need a raster, just a triangulation.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it is a function `interpolatePoint()`([code](http://qgis.org/api/qgsgridfilewriter_8cpp_source.html)). This function is called and then in initialized is created triangulation:

```
if ( mExportTriangulationToFile )
{
  dualEdgeTriangulation->saveAsShapefile( mTriangulationFilePath );
}
```

This how you can get only triangulation file from Interpolation Qgis plugin:

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsInterpolator, QgsTINInterpolator
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
from paths import *

resolution = 100
q5_edited = QgsVectorLayer(path_q5_layer, "CONTOUR", "ogr")
q20_edited = QgsVectorLayer(path_q20_layer, "CONTOUR", "ogr")

q5_index = q5_edited.fieldNameIndex('intpol')
q20_index = q20_edited.fieldNameIndex('intpol')

ld_q20 = QgsInterpolator.LayerData()
ld_q5 = QgsInterpolator.LayerData()

ld_q20.vectorLayer = q20_edited
ld_q20.zCoordInterpolation=False
ld_q20.InterpolationAttribute = q20_index
ld_q20.mInputType = 1 #1 = structureLines, 2 = breakLines

ld_q5.vectorLayer = q5_edited
ld_q5.zCoordInterpolation = False
ld_q5.interpolationAttribute = q5_index
ld_q5.mInputType = 1

itp = QgsTINInterpolator([ld_q20, ld_q5])
itp.setExportTriangulationToFile(True)

#path for TIN, not clipped
itp.setTriangulationFilePath(path_tin)

rect = q20_edited.extent()
ncol = int((rect.xMaximum() - rect.xMinimum())/resolution)
nrow = int((rect.yMaximum() - rect.yMinimum())/resolution)

# this is what you need only for dualedge triangulation file
currentYValue = rect.yMaximum() - resolution / 2.0
currentXValue = rect.xMinimum() + resolution / 2.0
itp.interpolatePoint(currentXValue, currentYValue)
```

The last three rows call is needed for triangulation file without writing interpolation raster. It generates only triangulation file.